# How to debug broken vim completefunc in haml files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, haml

I'm using [rails.vim](http://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/) and I love how you can use <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-u</kbd> in insert mode to autocomplete long method names like `distance_of_time_in_words` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. But for some reason it doesn't work in haml files and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong or how to fix it.

`:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-U` says the autocompletion is using `completefunc`. The haml file says its `completefunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete` (and it's the same in erb and helper files where <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-u</kbd> works fine.) I can't find where the `syntaxcomplete#Complete` magic is defined, but presumably it has something to do with the filetype syntax. My `.vim/syntax/haml.vim` comes from [vim-haml](http://github.com/tpope/vim-haml), so I tried removing it but the problem persists. 
Commenting out my entire `.vimrc` didn't help either. What else can I try?

UPDATE: I searched my vim config files and the only place that looks like it's doing anything with `syntaxcomplete#Complete` is in `autoload/rails.vim` and looks like this:

```
function! s:resetomnicomplete()
  if exists("+completefunc") && &completefunc == 'syntaxcomplete#Complete'
    if exists("g:loaded_syntax_completion")
      " Ugly but necessary, until we have our own completion
      unlet g:loaded_syntax_completion
      silent! delfunction syntaxcomplete#Complete
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions with # in name are defined in autoload scripts:

> A function that can be autoloaded has a name
>   like this:
>       :call filename#funcname()
>   When such a function is called, and it is not defined yet, Vim will search the
>   "autoload" directories in 'runtimepath' for a script file called
>   "filename.vim".  For example "~/.vim/autoload/filename.vim".

See `:help autoload`.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. But I don't have a ~/.vim/autoload/syntaxcomplete.vim file. I assume it's not a native vim thing because :help syntaxcomplete doesn't find anything.

Comment: syntaxcomplete.vim is a part of standard Vim distribution. You can find it in autoload/ directory where Vim is installed (e.g. /usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload). As far as I can see, syntaxcomplete is general syntax-based completion (not rails-specific). :help ft-syntax-omni will tell you more.

Comment: Thanks again. :help ft-syntax-omni led me in the right direction to finally get something working. The problem was that the syntax group that defined the rails helpers started with eruby rather than haml. So I hacked a fix by adding the following to autoload/rails.vim in an if &syntax == "haml" clause:
exe "syn keyword hamlRailsHelperMethod ".s:sub(s:helpermethods(),'<select\s+','')." contained containedin=@erubyRailsRegions"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file you're looking for is part of vim:

```
$ find /usr/share/vim/ -iname "syntaxcomplete.vim"
/usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload/syntaxcomplete.vim
```

There's a [vim.org page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3172) with the latest version of the script.

If you want to customize the completion, you can just write your own completion function. See `:help complete-functions`

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to use vim's simple completion. It completes with text from any of the open files, but can be customized. (See `:help 'complete'`)